Does pyinstaller conflict inside venv in Python 3.11 on Raspberrypi 4?
I am everything else but an experienced programmer. A few years ago it seemed easy to make an executable using pyinstaller (Python 3.5 on a Raspberry 3). This time, I get a list of errors, which to me have nothing to do with the project’s code. Even this simple project for testing produces the exact same list of errors when trying to package with pyinstaller.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rl/t_pyinstaller_venv/bin/pyinstaller", line 5, in <module>
    from PyInstaller.__main__ import _console_script_run
  File "/home/rl/t_pyinstaller_venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyInstaller/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from PyInstaller import compat
  File "/home/rl/t_pyinstaller_venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyInstaller/compat.py", line 97, in <module>
    is_musl = is_linux and "musl" in subprocess.run(["ldd"], capture_output=True, encoding="utf-8").stderr
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 550, in run
    stdout, stderr = process.communicate(input, timeout=timeout)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 1207, in communicate
    stdout, stderr = self._communicate(input, endtime, timeout)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 2101, in _communicate
    stderr = self._translate_newlines(stderr,
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 1084, in _translate_newlines
    data = data.decode(encoding, errors)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbb in position 45: invalid start byte
(t_pyinstaller_venv) rl@raspberrypi:~ $

As with the latest Raspberrypi OS (bookworm), the projects must be inside of a virtual environment. Could this conflict with pyinstaller? I would be very grateful for any hint on what is happening here!
